# Twitterbootstrapmvc in Areas not resolving

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using TwitterbootstrapMVC in a project, and today I moved code into  "AREAS"

The HTMLHelpers are not being recognized when I am coding, which is leading to a lot of mistakes, saying "No Extension Method 'Bootstrap' accepting a first argument .. could be found"

The code is compiling and running without fault, but the coding side is coming up with the 'red squiggly underline"

Any help with this would be appreciated

TIA, Mark

Answer (score 0):

This can be ignored as it started resolving once I restarted Visual Studio!